# Problem with ssh-agent, or git config, or github, or any other reason

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-agent

So I am trying to clone my repository via `ssh`.

For that purpose, I have:

- created private and public keys using `ssh-keygen`.
- Added the private key using `ssh-add`.
- Added the public key to a GitHub account.

And finally, when I try to `git clone` .. my remote repo I got an error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

P.S nothing from GitHub FAQ about the "Permission denied" topic helped me.

**EDIT**:

```
ssh -vT git@github.com

OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.118.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-5a455904
debug1: no match: babeld-5a455904
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:LsIWcaAcRR0Lh880/ImF1Ex9doM47aqEqt9rXcl3BTE c:/users/.../.ssh/github/key
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
warning: agent returned different signature type ssh-rsa (expected rsa-sha2-512)
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.118.3]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi Nickpofig! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3328, received 2484 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
1
s
```

Comment: Please run `ssh -vT git@github.com` and [edit] your question to include the ssh verbose output.

Comment: @rootkonda your comment does not answer my question, please be kind and provide a better explanation.

Comment: @Kenster post updated.

Comment: @NickPofig -  Your command in EDIT section doesn't have .com at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was specific to my system, so you wouldn't be able to help, however, thanks anyway. After research what is GIT_SSH_COMMAND about, I found out that git uses it in order to set user application as an establisher of ssh communication. In my case, I didn't have that variable listed in my environment, so I added "GIT_SSH" (also works fine for git) manually via the command line: `setx GIT_SSH C:/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe`. Just in case, check the path of your ssh.exe via command: `Get-Command ssh` (Get-Command just gives you a path of the given environment variable) and put it after GIT_SSH (your new environment variable, which would be used by git to establish ssh communication). And that's it.

Be aware, don't use just `set` command - it would add a variable only for a current terminal session, so it is useless in our case.

Of courses, your problem of cloning a git repository may have a different root. However, if you check your "GIT_SSH" variable being set that would eliminate my problem case in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can type:

```
set "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -Tv"
git clone git@github.com:<me>/<myrepo>
```

You will see what is going on, in particular if your `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa` key is used.

This is similar to `ssh -Tv git@github.com` (with, as noted `.com` at the end)

Comment: Updated. Sorry, that was a typo, I forgot to write it down.

Comment: So... The test ssh -Tv git@github.com is working. The clone should work. What is the exact URL you are cloning?

Comment: I use ssh url of my repository and I checked its correctness, so I think the problem is somewhere else. Do you know what possibly  could cause such error ? I currently don't have a single clue :/

Comment: Seeing the logs of git clone after a `set "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -Tv"` would help.

Comment: `set "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -Tv"
PS C:\....> git clone git@github.com:Nickpofig/something.git
Cloning into 'something'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
`
The log message hasn't been changed.

Comment: P.s I have access rights(it is my repository), I have a repository, I have copy-pasted ssh url address, I have correct public key in my github account. So, again, I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: @Nickpofig Strange, the log should have changed. Can you try in a CMD instead of a PS (PowerShell) session?

Comment: @Nickpofig I am sorry about the downvotes, and for any frustration Stack Overflow might cause. But I promise you, your question and excellent answer will help others. Which, in the grand sheme of things, is what matters.